# Filtering Get-WmiObject Class Property Output to include only value

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I've been utilizing Powershell to query items from a host using the "Get-WmiObject" cmdlet and the associated classes as part of a script.
In order to find the Computer Manufacturer I use the following Get-WMIObject command to output the returned property to a variable:

```
PS C:\temp\PS> $VmPhys = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem |Select-Object -Property Manufacturer
PS C:\temp\PS> write-host = $VmPhys
= @{Manufacturer=Dell Inc.}
```

The issue I have is that when I send the property value to the variable it also includes the property name and not just the value as per the above.

```
PS C:\temp\PS> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem |Select-Object -Property Manufacturer

Manufacturer
------------
Dell Inc.
```

Is there a way to exclude the property name and only export the value eg "Dell Inc." to the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-Expandproperty` instead of `property`

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manufacturer
```